# Perl IDE that is native to Windows and has good Perl integration

Tags: windows, ide, software-development, perl

Looking for Perl IDE, that has good Perl integration:

- Syntax Highlighting
- Autocomplete (ideally, syntax-aware)
- Ability to build function lists and jump to function definition from a function list
- Ability to run the Perl script you're editing, straight up.
- Ideally, ability to run your Perl script in a debugger with debugging GUI being your editor.

Don't care if the IDE is Perl-purposed or generic one with Perl related plugins.

Preferred environment is Windows but not really a deal-breaker for me.

I already know about UltraEdit, and use that, and it's not bad, but:

- its Perl syntax highlighter has issues (if you use a quote anywhere in a comment it will highlight ALL text after that comment as a string, till the next quote).
- it doesn't have a way to use the editor as debugger GUI
- Its autocomplete is... not very smart or syntax aware.

Tool cost isn't a big factor but if a version of the tool with Perl support costs more than baseline one, please indicate so.

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with Perl, but I'd recommend trying Sublime Text with the SublimeCodeIntel plugin (grab it through Sublime Package Control 3 after installation). I don't think it does debugging, but it should handle the other things.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Komodo IDE](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-ide).  It has Perl support including a graphical debugger, a regex debugger, and code refactoring.  If you don't need the debugging and refactoring capabilities, try [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit).  Komodo Edit is a free version of the Komodo IDE with fewer features.

Comment: How does it match the requirements? Explicitly asked for: Syntax highlighting, auto-completion, function-list jumping... Please [read our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) to see if you can incorporate some of these improvements into your answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Geany](http://www.geany.org/) contains several of the features you wanted. It definitely has syntax highlighting, ability to run, and function lists. I've never used the autocomplete, but it claims to have it, and I'm not sure about debugging. It may also have the comment highlighting issue, but I don't know for sure.